# jquery-ui.js close menu when menu item clicked

Tags: jquery-ui, menu, destroy

I am new to javascript and have been looking into jquery-ui.js.
There is a ui-menu function, which keeps the menu focused when the menu item is clicked. The menu closes when one clicks outside the menu

From the comments I can see, this keeps the menu ui from closing.

```
// Prevent focus from sticking to links inside menu after clicking
        // them (focus should always stay on UL during navigation).
        "mousedown .ui-menu-item": function( event ) {
            event.preventDefault();
        },
        "click .ui-menu-item": function( event ) {
            var target = $( event.target );
            var active = $( $.ui.safeActiveElement( this.document[ 0 ] ) );
            if ( !this.mouseHandled && target.not( ".ui-state-disabled" ).length ) {
                this.select( event );
```

It seems to be trying to open the menu from here

```
// Open submenu on click
                if ( target.has( ".ui-menu" ).length ) {
                    this.expand( event );
                } else if ( !this.element.is( ":focus" ) &&
                        active.closest( ".ui-menu" ).length ) {

                    // Redirect focus to the menu
                    this.element.trigger( "focus", [ true ] );

                    // If the active item is on the top level, let it stay active.
                    // Otherwise, blur the active item since it is no longer visible.
                    if ( this.active && this.active.parents( ".ui-menu" ).length === 1 ) {
                        clearTimeout( this.timer );
                    }
                }
```

Then I found this comment, which shows the menu being destroyed after the menu clicks outside it

```
        // Clicks outside of a menu collapse any open menus
    this._on( this.document, {
        click: function( event ) {
            if ( this._closeOnDocumentClick( event ) ) {
                this.collapseAll( event );
            }

            // Reset the mouseHandled flag
            this.mouseHandled = false;
        }
    } );
```

Very grateful to hear any of your thoughts :)

just created a fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/17cder9v/
:)

Comment: just created a jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/17cder9v/

Comment: Is there a question, or are you simply explaining the findings?

Comment: the question is, is it possible to do a "close on click"